# Add Animation on DataTemplate Items While loading in MAUI

Tags: maui

I sometimes use `CollectionView` and `BindableLayout` to load a data set. I am unsure how to add animations to these items when loading data sets.

Let's say I have the following examples, How can I add animation (any random one / basic) while loading each item?

```
<CollectionView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding List} 
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}">
     <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"  ItemSpacing="10"/>
     </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
</CollectionView>

<HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="1" Spacing="10"
          BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding List}" 
          BindableLayout.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}">
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

Data Template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <Image Source="{Binding Path}" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: By animation do you mean something to show while the content is loading (like a ActivityIndicator) or some kind of transition then you add the item ?

Comment: I am very interested to know, how are you loading them item by item.

Comment: thanks, that's a simple data template with CollectionView or BindableLayout. The data comes from ViewModel. I want to simply transition/fade (any animation) items while loading them. I am not interested in showing ActivityIndicator or Skeleton. Right now the items just appear as they are added to the ObservableCollection in ViewModel.

Comment: At the beginning of MAUI there was OnAttached property which we could add to the Data Template Item. That property was helpful to add animations, but that's not there anymore.

Comment: This? https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyEffects

Comment: No that's just a skeleton. This video at 6:23 shows the AttachedHandler event which we can use to add animations. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7N3cbDd2y2k&t=385s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add animations using [Behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/behaviors?view=net-maui-7.0) and more specifically using [AnimationBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/animation-behavior) from the Community Toolkits.

Currently there is only a `FadeAnimation` available but you can easily [create new animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/animations/#creating-custom-animations). Here is a simple example :

```
<CollectionView x:Name="Collection">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:SomeDataClass">
            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding SomeProp}" />
                <Label Text="Boup">
                    <Label.Behaviors>
                        <toolkit:AnimationBehavior EventName="Loaded">
                            <toolkit:AnimationBehavior.AnimationType>
                                <local:PaintTheRainbowAnimation Length="1000" />
                            </toolkit:AnimationBehavior.AnimationType>
                        </toolkit:AnimationBehavior>
                    </Label.Behaviors>
                </Label>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Using this animation class :

```
class PaintTheRainbowAnimation : BaseAnimation
{
    public async override Task Animate(VisualElement view)
    {
        await view.BackgroundColorTo(Colors.Red);
        await view.BackgroundColorTo(Colors.Orange);
        await view.BackgroundColorTo(Colors.Yellow);
        await view.BackgroundColorTo(Colors.Green);
        await view.BackgroundColorTo(Colors.Blue);
        await view.BackgroundColorTo(Colors.Indigo);
        await view.BackgroundColorTo(Colors.Violet);
    }
}
```